# Xamarin override image of Nuget Package

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget

I have a Xamarin.Forms app 'Main'.

A separate ios project library 'Helper', which has a Page and image XYZ.png used inside this page of this library.
This 'Helper' is consumed as Nuget Package in 'Main' app.

'Main' app also has XYZ.png.

While running the app, Page shows image from 'Helper' not from 'Main'.

Any idea how to display image from 'Main' app.

Comment: 1.Why you don't  set the name of `png` with different names? 2.Do you have an `image asset` in your Xamarin.iOS app? If so, you can use it by calling the FromBundle method of the UIImage class. For Example: `MonkeyImage.Image = UIImage.FromBundle ("PurpleMonkey");` , you can refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/displaying-an-image?tabs=windows) for more details.

Comment: Helper library project has the page and image both, this image I want to override in Main app